# Share Intent list menu available on device orientation changed (shareActionProvider)

Tags: android, android-intent, shareactionprovider

After couple of hours of investigations and trying to find a solution I’ve decided to write here my problem in idea that maybe someone else face it also and found a fix for it.
I have a application with a menu, one of the options being a **Share option**, declare like this in menu xml file:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
          android:title="Share"/>
```

In `onOptionsItemSelected` method I create and set the share intent:

```
private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_share:
                MenuItem actionItem = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
                shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
                shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

When pressing the Share menu option the list with apps to share is displayed.
[image]
What I want is when I rotate the device that list to be visible, but instead is disappearing.  To mention that I can’t use `android:configChanges` in order to prevent the activity from being recreated.

I wanted first to see how can I open that share apps list programmatically.

a). Calling the below method nothing visual happens; it just updates the `ShareActionProvider`

```
public void showShareItemList() {
    MenuItem actionItem = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
    shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
}
```

b). Calling the below method opens a new activity – but not a menu options list like in the picture above.

```
public void showShareItemList2(){
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
        sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share"));
    }
```

Result:
[image]

c).The below method just opens the menu option:

```
public void showShareItemList3() {
    openOptionsMenu(); // programmatically open the options menu
}
```

**So, is there a way to open the share item list of applications programmatically ? Or at least is there a way to press menu key programmatically ( = programatically select a menu item)?**

Another issue is **how can I know if the share list is visible on orientation changed?**

For this I’m using  a `boolean` variable  `private boolean isShareOptionMenuListVisible = false;` which I save it on method `onSaveInstanceState()` and restored it in `onCreate()` method.
I make `isShareOptionMenuListVisible = true` when the Share item is pressed, but I could not find a way to make it to false when is not visible anymore.
Using the override method `onOptionsMenuClosed` is not helping me because this *“is called whenever the options menu is being closed”* (this is in documentation, even if I can say this is not real because in my app is never called), and I want to know when the Share apps options menu is being closed.

Here is a sample documented project which demonstrates all the above issues: [project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4t2di1x70ljkt3/ShareIntent.zip).

Any help is welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SDK 11 or above, you can register to receive a callback when the (or any) action item's menu is showing, including your ShareActionProvider:

```
getActionBar().addOnMenuVisibilityListener(new ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMenuVisibilityChanged(boolean isVisible) {
        ...
    }

});
```

This method is also supported in ActionBarSherlock, but for some reason the listener is never actually called.